# Why is it necessary to define a parameterised lambda expression when specifying state object?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

For example take the following code snippet:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(state => Greet("Hello"), "Greeting");
```

I'm trying to understand why there's a need to pass "Greeting" to the `state` parameter.

Why could it not be like so:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Greet("Hello"), "Greeting");
```

Comment: Then what would happen to the state?

Comment: `state` contains the current state. You can use its value in your lambda call

Comment: @knittl Ah I see, I suspected that maybe the case, many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the only methods defined in `TaskFactory` which takes only two parameters as well as `object state` as second parameter.

```
public Task StartNew(Action<object> action, object state);
public Task<TResult> StartNew<TResult>(Func<object, TResult> function, object state);
```

As you can see `Action<object>` needs single parameter to be passed in and also `Func<object, TResult>` requires single parameter of type `object` but in your case you haven't satisfied any of them so compiler is not happy.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Greet("Hello"), "Greeting");
```

This can neither be converted to `Func<object, TResult>` nor `Action<object> action`.

Answer (score 2):

It's an optimization. Consider this, which allocates a closure:

```
MyState s;
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Greet(s.Greeting));
```

While this one will use a cached delegate as it does not capture anything:

```
MyState s;
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(o => Greet(((MyState)o).Greeting), s);
```

Another rarer but equally valid use is that the object will be assigned to the `IAsyncResult.AsyncState` property of the returned `Task`.

Comment: Wrong. No such optimization, check out my answer for details.

Comment: The optimization is real, but yes his code as given was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because `TaskFactory.StartNew<TResult> Method (Func<TResult>)` must return a result and given that lambda expression is evaluated from the right to left to determine the result you will need state to  infer the result  type  as `Func<object, TResult>` must receive an object as first argument and return a result

Comment: Compiler is almost clever in type inference, that is not the case here, There is no matching overload resolution!. refer my answer for details

Answer (score 1):

Better to think of it list this

```
    foreach(var s in myList)
    {  
          Print(s);
    }
```

is equivalent to

```
   myList.ForEach(s => Print(s));
```

You don't need to use the s, but you need to give it a name

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can see the overloaded versions of `StartNew` method.You are using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) version:

```
public Task StartNew(Action<Object> action,Object state)
```

According to documentation:

> state : An object containing data to be used by the **action** delegate.

You want this but there is no overloaded version like that:

```
public Task StartNew(Action action,Object state)
```

So when you specify a state parameter you need to use `Action<Object>`.